# How to record internal audio loud?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-recording, recordmydesktop

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm new to Linux.
I'm trying to record my screen with internal audio only(no mic). I've tried various applications such as simpleScreenRecorder, recordMyDestop and also online screen recorder.

The problem is the audio volume of the output file is always very low even though I'm playing and recording at 100% volume.

I've tried different output formats still same issue.

My device is Dell latitude e5450. And when I'm on Windows, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ubuntu volume levels]

1 - Click the volume button on the top bar.

2 - Click on settings.

3 - Make sure you are in the sound configuration tab.

4 - Make sure the volume level sliders are not too low. If so, turn the switches to the right to increase the volume.

5 - Test the audio recording again.